# Diff/Compare Tool That Lets Me Write Comments On Differing Lines

Tags: diff, compare

I'm looking for a diff/compare tool that shows differing lines from two text files, and gives me a space to comment on those files. Ideally this application would have three panes, pane one would be file A, pane two would file B and pane three would be a comment I can enter to on why the files are different.

We're going to be using this diff tool to compare test and production environments. Sometimes it'll be justifiable that the two files are different but we need to have a space to explain why. I'd rather not write those comments in the files themselves.

I've used TortosieMerge, WinDiff and Beyond Compare. I like beyond compare the most because it lets me see the whole file, just the differing lines or the differing lines in context.

Tools that sit inside Visual Studio or eclipse are fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might want to use a code review tool for this (even if you're not really performing code reviews).  They record diffs in a database and allow comments on those diffs.

A couple free ones are:

- [CodeStriker](http://codestriker.sourceforge.net/) - I've used this and it works pretty well, but required more tweaking and mucking around in Perl that I'd have liked (that was a while ago, though)
- [Review Board](http://www.review-board.org/) - never used this, but it sure looks nice.  I'm trying to get it installed at my current place of work.

Comment: While I was thinking more along the lines of a standalone desktop app, this does make sense. Can you recomend anything that would integrate with Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Yeah - these tools are geared toward collaboration so they're server based, but there's nothing that would prevent you from installing CodeStriker on your own machine with you being the sole user - but it's definitely not a simple 'click through' installation.  But I did it, so it can't be too bad...  And sorry - no TFS recommendation.  I've only had limited experience with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a high-efficiency software CodeGen to you. It's not only include TextCompare tools, but another Codec/Database tools is supported as well.
For more detail, please kindly access the Github repository.

https://github.com/work7z/CodeGen

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31413311)